# How to add a JAR file to an existing gradle project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, aspose-cells

I have a jar file for **Aspose Cells for Java** that I want to add to an existing Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1.

If I go to **View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle**, I see the gradle window like so but I don't know what to click. I tried right-clicking on **Dependencies** but nothing happened. Should I click the **+** sign? I think not.

[image]

How do I do that?

1. Is it okay to add it the non-gradle way, i.e. by clicking **File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies** tab **-> +** sign?
2. What is the gradle way of doing it? Where do I find the **build.gradle** file to edit? I could see it a few commits earlier but I am having a hard time finding my way around the IDE. I can see the **build.gradle** file in Windows explorer. Should I edit it by hand outside of the IDE?

Comment: Why don't you want to use some central maven repository instead of storing jars locally?

Comment: It's a commercial product I don't host.

Comment: Not sure as it can be found on maven central - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aspose/aspose-cells

Comment: Thank you. I checked before posting. Couldn't find it.

Comment: And by the way, no-one answered if this is okay to add it in a non-gradle way - no it isn't okay as your project will become non-portable.

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate that. That's really important. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
compile files('/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/<DEPENDENCY>.jar')
or
//put jar file in lib directory of project.
compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar']) }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I kind of know what to type in. I can't find the file. Should I open it in the IDE? Is it okay to edit it outside the IDE?

Comment: Editing can be done using any editor. Get into project folder, if build.gradle is not present then create new and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

**How to add Jar in existing project in Intellij**

1. Goto File->project structure-> Libraries tab -> + sign?
2. Select Java from the list
3. Select jar file from file system
4. Choose apply and ok

**How to add dependency in gradle project**
  1. If your project is gradle project it will have build.gradle in root path of project.
  2. Open build.gradle and add it in the dependencies block in required decencies.
  3. Make sure that repositories for libraries should be already included.
  (Usually if library is on mavenCentral then it should be like mavenCentral() )

Comment: Thank you. I thought as much. The only problem is, I can't see how to edit the file inside the IDE. Is there a way? Or should I edit the file outside the IDE?

Comment: Thank you so much. If we could, I would mark this answer too as the right one because I found it very helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the directory to the `repositories{}` and simply add the jar as every other.

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'path/to/your/dir'
   }
}
```

then

```
dependencies {
   compile name: 'yourJar'
}
```

---

**BTW:** If you take it from [GitHub](https://github.com/aspose-cells/Aspose.Cells-for-Java) it should be published to some repo I presume.

What about this one? [Aspose.Cells](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aspose/aspose.cells)