# Why does this dependency not show up as one added by Gradle even when it was?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Following the suggestion on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45792184/303685), I added the jars I wanted to reference in a folder named **lib** in the project root and I added the following gradle dependencies to my project:

```
dependencies {

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'

    compile files('/lib/aspose-cells-17.02.0.jar');
    compile files('/lib/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar');
}
```

Now, when I look at **File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies** (tab) in IntelliJ, it shows every other dependency as having been added by Gradle except the two files I included above.

[image]

Is that the way it is supposed to appear? Have I done anything wrong? Or is there another way to make the word **Gradle:** appear in front of those dependencies?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  The two dependencies you cite are right there at the top.  I think the rest are brought in as dependencies of your dependencies, not explicitly by you but by Gradle.

Comment: @duffymo Some of the rest of them are also included in the **build.gradle** file which I haven't included in the question. I have updated the question to include them as well. My only worry is: the word **Gradle:** does not appear in front of the two I added from the **lib** folder. Is that okay or will they not be deployed when I deploy my code?

Comment: I wouldn't have any /lib folder anymore if I were using Gradle.  I use Maven all the time now.   Why do you not put all your dependencies under Gradle?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 it should be fine.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you.